# Approximate independence for fixpoints of random permutations

Tags: permutations, random-variables, poisson-distribution

Let $F_n$ be the random variable that is the number of fixed points of a random permutation on $n$ elements.  As $n \to \infty$, the distribution of $F_n$ approaches a Poisson distribution with mean 1.  This can easily be shown via direct calculation.

I would like a more intutive proof.  For large $n$ the events that any particular $k << n$ elements are fixed are approximately independent.  If we are assume they are exactly independent, it is immediate that the limit is Poisson with mean 1.  Is there a way to make this reasoning precise, ideally with a minimum of calculation?

Comment: There is this method:  https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1177012015

Comment: It is easy to show that the mean is $1$ for any $n$, so the real issue is the Poisson distribution limit.  If you know that the number of derangements (no fixed points) of $m$ values is the rounded $\lceil m!/e \rfloor$, then the probability of having $k$ fixed points out of $n$ is ${n \choose k}\lceil (n-k)!/e \rfloor / n!$ which has a limit of $e^{-1}/k!$ as $n$ increases, implying convergence in distribution to a Poisson distribution with pmf $\lambda^k e^{-\lambda} / k!$ with $\lambda=1$

Comment: @Henry: Yes, that's the calculation.  It's an easy calculation, but I'm still interested in trying to do it via approximate independence methods (such as the Chen-Stein method from the first comment).

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving - perhaps so, but the approximate independence amounts to little more than saying $\lceil m!/e \rfloor \approx m!/e$